# WCF ServiceRouter & Transactions

Tags: wcf, transactions, routes

How can I configure the service router to enable transactions, because the backend service uses them and this feature doesnt work since I introduced the ServiceRouter in the middle of the Client & Server dialog.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't figured it out, have a look at the `IDuplexSessionRouter` contract.

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517420.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Routing service is only intermediary. It doesn't participate in transaction. It is just something that should be as much transparent to client and service as possible.

Transactions in WCF are provided as additional messages send over wire. So my understanding is that if you are using router you must correctly route these messages as well. I have to say I have no idea how to do it without reading and fully understanding WS-AT protocol specification.

But maybe I'm wrong. In such case start with configuring routing service with transactional binding same as your client and service.

Comment: I have already tried to configure the enpoint with transactional binding configuration like the configuration that the end services have . Anyway, thanks for your answer I appreciate